# How to run webapp on Azure with classic mode

Tags: azure

I want to run the app with classic mode, but in Azure how should I do that?
The only idea I can figure is startup script? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deploy your website in [a WebRole](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/cloud-services/), and [not WebSite](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/). Doing so, you have the ability to run [a startup task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974418.aspx) in elevated mode.
Put the following line in your startup task script:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /applicationPoolDefaults.managedPipelineMode:"Classic" /commit:apphost
```

And this will do the trick.